# From a Python dict filled with arrays to a dict representing all combinations

Tags: python

I want a function of which the input is this:

```
my_dict = {
    'foo':[1,2,3]
    'bar': [True, False]
}
```

And the output is that:

```
results = {
    'foo':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
    'bar': [True, False, True, False, True, False]
}
```

Context: I'm writing my own "cross-validation" function for machine learning. So I need to flatten all parameters to feed my model. I don't know in advance how many parameters there are neither their names. So I need to parse the input dictionary.

I feel like I'm making it more complicated than needed, so that's why I'm asking help. Maybe a function already exists to that, even if I didn't find it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Idea: do a cartesian product (list tuples with 1st element from foo, 2nd from bar, 3rd from...), then reassign all first elements of the tuples as value of 1st key (foo), all 2nd elements as values of 2nd key...

Comment: so whats the general rule here? if i read a dicts with two keys and each key has a list whats the rule to know how to expand each list. in this example you repeat each element in foo twice, but in bar you expand the list 3 times alternating the values. so do you have a general rule to follow?

Comment: you want to repat all entries of your dictionary once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to do it is the following

```
import itertools

keys = list(my_dict.keys())
product = list(itertools.product(*list(my_dict.values())))
results = {keys[i]: [item[i] for item in product] for i in range(len(keys))}
```

which gives the results you are after.

```
print(results)
{'foo': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'bar': [True, False, True, False, True, False]}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot. I didn't know itertools.product()!